# Web3 in the browser

Tags: web3js

Importing `web3@1.0.0-beta.55` in a stencil+typescript file for a frontend application directly triggers an error, even without using the imported Web3 object whatsoever.

`import Web3 from 'web3';`

->

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'WebSocket' of undefined`

This seems expected as Stencil don't use Webpack. Which is the best way to use Web3 1.0 in the browser? Is there a browser-compatible version of it?

Comment: I'm confused as to why Webpack is related? Web3 1.0 certainly works fine in browsers. (That's probably its main target.)

Comment: I made this work by forking https://github.com/NoahZinsmeister/web3-webpacked and adding 
`externals: {'websocket': 'window.WebSocket'}` into the webpack config.

Are you sure webpack should be compatible with a browser without webpack? Maybe some bundled versions already used webpack?

the latest seems to be not really a bundle
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@1.0.0-beta.55/dist/web3.esm.min.js